# AWS webserver is down

Tags: amazon-web-services

I inherited an aws webserver (which is running on what seems like Ubuntu OS) it is no longer responding. Then I restarted the server and it responded as usual for a couple of hours. Now the server is down again. I didn't ssh to the machine yet because I don't have a pem key file and I don't have an account. I only have the aws account.

Is it possible to generate a new pem file and login to the server to examine what the problem is?

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault - see the help center.

Comment: And seriously, there are so many things wrong with your setup that you tick every one of the items in the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new duplicate instance from a snapshot. When creating the new instance you will be offered to create or us an existing PEM file, choose to create one.